# type org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, authentication

Hi there so I'm trying to create a Spring Security Login page which roots back to my DB(sql server) where my credentials are stored.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

//Some imports like JDBC template and beanrowmapper are present but dont mind them.. as i was trying somethings out..

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigWithDB extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;  

@Bean 
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder1() { 
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
}


 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()) // this is where i get the error//
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("Select UserName, Password, Enable FROM LoginDetails WHERE Username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("Select UserName, Role FROM LoginDetails WHERE Username=?");
        
        
    }

 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();     
    }
}
```

And the error goes like :
**The type org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**

Comment: Which is propably because you aren't using `spring-boot-starter-security` but rather individual and non compatible versions.

Comment: @M.Deinum      
Yep you're right. Actually I'm using both spring-boot-starter-security and the individual one. Its just that i was using the older version and not the latest one. Thanks for clarifying..

Comment: If you have `spring-boot-starter-security` you don't need the individual ones.

Comment: @M.Deinum   
Yea got it.. took them down already. Thanks again